# How to write following aggregate method using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

Consider a list of popular items as

```
 ids_of_popular_items <- c('12345678','87654321')
```

Consider a data frame `input_data` with two columns `session_id` and `item_id`.

```
  session_id   item_id
1    1806169 643078800
2    1806169 643078800
3    2116064 214840661
4    2116064 214840663
....
```

As shown, session `2116064` has two items `214840661` and `214840661`.
Now I want to see how popular these two items are in the whole dataset `input_data`. That is the `table()` on the list of these items. So each aggregated session will now have a sorted list of counts of items which belong to that session. e.g. if `214840661` appears 100 times and `214840661` appears 200 times in the `input_data`, the aggregated value for session `2116064` should be a vector (200, 100).

```
  session_id   item_counts
1    1806169   (40)
2    2116064   (200, 100)
....
```

I want to consider only those items in each session which are not present in `ids_of_popular_items`.

I have achieved this using `aggregate` method as follows (as aggregate allows to return a list for each aggregated record):

```
all_popularity <- aggregate(input_data$item_id, 
                            FUN = function(items) {(table(input_data_without_popular$item_id[input_data_without_popular$item_id %in% items]))}, 
                            by = list(yoochoose_predictors$session_id))
```

But because of the large size of the dataset (around 2 million rows), it takes lot of time to compute. 
I have used `data.table` for simple aggregation and it works much faster. I would like to know how to achieve this using `data.table`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(input_data)[, .N,.(session_id, item_id)][, 
    list(item_counts=  sprintf('(%s)', toString(N))) , session_id]
```

#### Update

I am not sure about the expected output, may be

```
setDT(input_data)[!item_id %chin% ids_of_popular_items][,
        .N,.(session_id, item_id)][, 
        list(item_counts=  sprintf('(%s)', toString(N))) , session_id]
```

Comment: How can I exclude those items which are present in `ids_of_popular_items`?

Comment: @Sangram Sorry, what are those `ids_of_popular_items?  It would have been better if you show a reproducible example with expected result

Comment: @Sangram Never mind, I found your `ids_of_popular_items` in the beginning of the post

Comment: @Sangram Do you want to exclude the `session_id` or `item_id` that corresponds to the `ids_of_popular_items`

Comment: I want to "exclude" all items from a particular session, whose `item_id` is present in `ids_of_popular_items`. Thus I want only NON-Popular items to be considered.

Comment: what is `%chin%`? Sorry, but I am new to R.

Comment: @Sangram I assumed that the 'item_id' is character class as your `ids_of_popular_items` seems to be `character`.  It would be a a bit faster to use `%chin%` instead of `%in%`

Comment: It seems like you have calculated the count of `item_id` only within the particular `session_id`. I want to have the count of `item_id` in the whole `input_data`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Sangram I checked your `aggregate` code, it is using `table` within `session_id`.  The equivalent without using `table` would be to get the `.N` for both the groups and then paste the `N` by `session_id`.  If you have doubts, then please check with a small example with the aggregate and this code

Comment: Thanks for the help @akrun. I will definitely check this and get back to you. Thanks for your valuable time!